# How to debug two RecyclerViews that suddenly stopped working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I was working on an Android project that features two fragments on the main activity with one RecyclerView in each of them. It was looking good and functioning as intended, then somewhere along the way something broke and now neither is populating with anything. I'm not sure how to even begin to debug this, as everything looks correct to me. I will just focus on one of the RecyclerViews for the code below. The other one is imported from another project, so it has even less reason to break as I didn't code it! If you need any more information let me know as I am learning as I go here.

I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, restarting Android Studio in case it was a weird cache issue. I have combed over the code but nothing jumps out at me and Android Studio is not raising any errors. The project builds and loads but the Recycler Views are devoid of content.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation project(':crunchycalendar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1'}
```

CardsFragment.kt

```
class CardsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_cards) {

var sampleDidits : Array<Didit> = arrayOf(
    Didit("Walk 15 minutes around the block with your dog", "Grab the earbuds and get outside", R.drawable.footsteps),
    Didit("Meditate 20 minutes", "This flavor text is too long man chill out", R.drawable.meditation),
    Didit("Take your meds", "Withdrawal ain't fun", R.drawable.pill_bottle)
)

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val binding = FragmentCardsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

    // Add the following lines to create RecyclerView
    val recyclerView = binding.cardsRecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    val snapHelper: SnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager;

    recyclerView.adapter = CardViewAdapter(sampleDidits);

    return binding.root
}
```

}

fragment_cards.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cf_constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

CardViewAdapter.kt

```
class CardViewAdapter(private val didit_tasks: Array<Didit>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val cv = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.didit_card, parent, false) as CardView
    return ViewHolder(cv)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // This is where data is added to the card view
    val cardView = holder.cardView
    val mainText = cardView.findViewById<View>(R.id.maintext) as TextView
    val streakText = cardView.findViewById<View>(R.id.streak_text) as TextView
    val flavorText = cardView.findViewById<View>(R.id.flavorText) as TextView
    val diditIcon = cardView.findViewById<View>(R.id.didit_icon) as ImageView
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.context, didit_tasks[position].icon)
    val streakString = didit_tasks[position].currentStreakString + " Day Streak"
    diditIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    mainText.text = didit_tasks[position].mainText
    flavorText.text = didit_tasks[position].flavorText
    streakText.text = streakString
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return didit_tasks.size
}

class ViewHolder(val cardView: CardView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    cardView
)
```

Update:

It appears to be an issue not with my Recycler Views but with my Fragments. None of the fragments are loading up and I'm not sure why.

Comment: In fragment are you passing the list & then in adapter are you updating the list and calling notifyDatasetChanged() ?

Comment: Yes the list is being passed in the line recyclerView.adapter = CardViewAdapter(sampleDidits); Not sure about how to use notifyDatasetChanged. I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be within my MainActivity.kt file. Under the onCreate function I had both `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

AND

`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`

Removing the former line solved the issue so all fragments loaded properly